# How do I progmatically add a Quick Launch link using the WSS 3 Web Services?

Tags: sharepoint, wss, wss-3.0

I'm trying to create a link for a Document Library I've created in the Documents Quick Launch section via the web services, but I can't see/find the API to do it.

I've found plenty of examples using the Object Model, but I'm not able to use it for various reasons.

So can anyone provide an example of doing it via the Web Services?

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Add SharePoint Document List to Quick Launch through Web Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649487/add-sharepoint-document-list-to-quick-launch-through-web-services)